# how can i run cron jobs with PHP?

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu

I'm running ubuntu 10.04 and have installed php5 via the following:

```
sudo aptitude install libapache2-mod-php5 php5 php5-common php5-curl php5-dev php5-gd php5-imagick php5-mcrypt php5-memcache php5-mhash php5-mysql php5-pspell php5-snmp php5-sqlite php5-xmlrpc php5-xsl
```

In my research, the following is an example of how to run cron as PHP:

```
00 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/john/myscript.php
```

the problem is... i'm looking in my /usr/bin/ folder... and I do NOT see any PHP folder or symlink... basically /usr/bin/php is non-existant and I need this to run my PHP scripts as cron jobs.

can someone tell me why (after a successful php installation) "/usr/local/bin/php" does not exist? I have check multiple online sources and "/usr/bin/php" should exist by default.

Please help!

Comment: You should first install php cli:
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
and then the /usr/bin/php will exist.

For more details about CronJobs in PHP see: 
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cron syntax is basically ok.

Try a...

```
whereis php
```

...or...

```
whereis php5
```

...to find where your php bin folder is located.

Comment: you can also try `which php` or `which php5`

Comment: Very true. I guess there are even more ways to find the directory via bash. I'm used to `whereis`.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP executable will be in /usr/bin/php.

Comment: in my distro it is /usr/local/bin/php

Answer (score 1):

Some new server's (2015+), also use `/usr/local/bin/php` for the php path.
so basically `/usr/local/bin/php (path of file)`

Answer (score 0):

Each linux distribution may/will place php in their own location. /usr/local is ment for programs you build yourself, and the distros will generally never put standard packages in there.

Doing a

```
whereis php
```

on Ubunto 10.04 tells me it is located in

```
/usr/bin/php
```

So you should replace /usr/local/bin/php with that as in:

```
00 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/john/myscript.php
```

You could also ask your distribution package system for a list of files that have been installed by the php5 package. That would reveal where your php binary is installed.

Comment: thanks Aron. I realized my question was wrong... I was actually looking for  /usr/bin/php, (without the local) but did not find it in /usr/bin/php...  when I tried whereis php... i got no results. any thoughts?

Comment: What does 'dpkg -s php5' and 'dpkg -L php5' say?