# PHP script only executing from command line when command is run from script's directory

Tags: php, shell, unix, command-line, cron

I am trying to run this script from the command line:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?php
$myfile = fopen("cc.log", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "Success \n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile); 
?>
```

And it works, but only when I cd into the directory of the script and run:

```
/usr/local/bin/php test_script.php
```

This also works:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/<username>/public_html/test_script.php
```

but not when I leave the directory.

Comment: Are you on Linux?

Comment: @cosinepenguin I'm accessing a Linux server via PuTTy on Windows

Comment: Have you made the test_script.php file executable? (`chmod 755 test_script.php`).

Comment: Also, do you get any errors when you try running from outside the directory, or does it not return anything?

Comment: @cosinepenguin I just entered that command with no luck. And no errors, it returns nothing

Comment: Were you "`cd`'d" into the directory containing your test_script.php file when you ran `chmod 755 test_script.php`?

Comment: @cosinepenguin Yes

Comment: Wait, when you say "no luck" did it error out, or have no error? Because it probably actually worked. If you run `ls -al` you can see if your file is executable (the permissions for the test_script.php file should look like this: `-rwxr-xr-x`). If that is true, you should be able to run the file just by invoking `./test_script.php`.

Comment: The permissions are `-rwxr-xr-x` and I can run it, but when I leave, I can't run it with  `path/to/test_script.php`

Answer (score 1):

Solved by changing line 3 of `test_script.php` from:

```
$myfile = fopen("cc.log", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
```

to an absolute path:

```
$myfile = fopen("/home/<username>/public_html/cc.log", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
```

The original script created a `cc.log` file in the directory from where the command was called and appended about 50 "Success" messages xD

Answer (score 0):

A more *formal* answer to the original question:

Your file (test_script.php) needs to be made executable to be able to be run from anywhere. This can be done with chmod:

```
chmod 755 test_script.php
```

and results in the file being able to be run by invoking.

```
./test_script.php
```

And now, drumroll please, you should be able to run the file by invoking it like this:

```
./path/to/test_script.php
```

That dot at the front of the path should allow you to run the script as an executable without doing anything else.

Hope it helps/works!

(If it doesn't work comment and I'll boot up my Linux machine and try to replicate it!)

**EDIT**

Ok, that's weird that it doesn't work! Shoot! Is the PHP CLI (command line interface) installed on your Linux server? If so I would encourage you to try:

```
php /path/to/your/test_script.php
```

Hope that second suggestion helps!

**EDIT 2**

Aha moment number 2!!

I believe your php should be installed here: `/usr/bin/php`, having it in the local folder will not allow you to properly invoke it from another directory!

To download yourself a new installation of php, run

`sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5`

You will also have to change your script header to `#!/usr/bin/php`.

This was a [good source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273056/how-can-i-run-cron-jobs-with-php) for this third edit! I really hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you but still no luck. `./test_script.php` works but when I navigate up one level in the directory, `./path/test_script.php` does not. But it should! I see it used in tutorials etc. but no luck for me! Even absolute path only works from within the folder (in this case, the public_html folder)

Comment: My second suggestion is to use the php CLI! That might help, I edited my answer... Here's where I got the idea for using the CLI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34396443/i-am-connecting-to-a-server-using-putty-can-i-run-php-scripts-on-that-if-i-can

Comment: In response to your edit: still nothing! And it seems to be installed. I type `which php-cli` and get `/usr/bin/php-cli`
And `php-cli -v` returns: `PHP 5.4.45 (cli) ...`

Comment: Aha! And where is your php itself? I think it should also be in /usr/bin/ (`/usr/bin/php` not `/usr/bin/local/php`)!

Comment: `which php` returns `/usr/local/bin/php`

Comment: Solved! See my answer